# Can I sort groups of rows in Excel so that the rows remained grouped after being sorted?

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-2010

I have a list of transactions that I will be importing into Quickbooks, and because of their file format requirements, each transaction takes up 3 rows in Excel. Is it possible to sort the transactions by date (which is in column D of the first and second of the three rows), while keeping the rows grouped by transaction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use custom sort by two columns - for each transaction add one column with unique number (maybe you already has one) and then sort first by that column and second by your desired column with date

Comment: I'm a little confused by your suggestion. Wouldn't sorting by the unique ID then by the date give me a list sorted by ID, and since there are no duplicate ID's, the sorting by date would be irrelevant? Also, it's worth pointing out that the 3rd row of each transaction does not have the date in it, it is all blank except for the first column which indicates the end of the transaction as "ENDTRNS", and this cannot be changed.

Comment: the same unique ID for all records of one unique transaction - if something is odd in what I'm saying please add some example structure of your file to your question

Answer (score 0):

I created a new column and used a function where, if it is a different transaction then assign a new value, but if it isn't then just keep the same:

```
=IF(NOT(B2=B1), Q1+1,Q1)
```

This will for example give different numbers to your transactions. And then you can sort by this new column.

```
=IF(NOT(B2=B1), RAND(),Q1)
```

Use this if you want to do it at random, and then sort by that column